# Handling several types of messages over a web socket connection

Tags: json, swift, ios, websocket, cocoa-touch

I have a `UIViewController` with a Socket Connection established once `viewDidLoad`.

This web socket is a multi-directional channel to exchange data between the iOS client app and the backend.

I have implemented the delegate methods and the `ViewController` listens to the updates from the socket. The received data is a JSON String, I convert it to `JSON` object using `SwiftyJSON` library. The JSON will be one of a 3 possible types I have already created the data model for. Then, I parse the JSON, create an object from my pre-defined Types, and append to an array. All done in the delegate method.

This is not a good coding practice because:

- I want to be able to use the established socket connection in different parts of the app.
- I want to abstract the JSON parsing into different parts so I just check the type of the model I need to create, and this calls the appropriate JSON parses.

Here's an example of the delegate method running in my `ChatLogViewController`

```
private var socket: WebSocket?
private var chatTableViewCell = [ChatTableViewCell]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: streamUrl!)!)
    self.socket?.delegate = self
    self.socket?.connect()
}


func websocketDidReceiveMessage(socket: WebSocket, text: String) {
    let jsonObj = JSON(parseJSON: text)
    let text = activity["text"].string
    let entities = activity["entities"].arrayValue

    for dict in entities {

        if let type = dict["type"].string {

            if type == "restaurant" {
                // parse the JSON and create Resturant object and append to the array
                if let restaurants = dict["restaurant"].array {
                    var restaurantsHolder = [Restaurant]()
                    for restaurant in restaurants {
                        guard let name = restaurant["name"].string, let image = restaurant["image"].string else { return }
                        let restaurant = Restaurant(name: name, vendorLogo: URL(string: image))
                        restaurantsHolder.append(restaurant)
                    }
                    addCardOfType(restaurant: restaurantsHolder)
                }
            } else if type == "category" {
                // parse the JSON and create Category object and append to the array
                if let categories = dict["category"].array {
                    var categories = [Category]()
                    for category in categories {
                        guard let name = category["name"].string, let imageStringUrl = category["imageUrl"].string else { return }
                        let botModel = category.description
                        let category = Category(name: name, imageUrl: imageStringUrl)
                    categories.append(category)
                    }
                    addCardOfType(categories: categoriesHolder)
                }
            } else if type == "item" {
                // parse the JSON and create Item object and append to the array
                if let items = dict["item"].array {
                    var itemsPreview = [Item]()

                    for item in items {
                        guard let itemTitle = item["title"].string,
                        let restaurantLogo = item["_restaurant"]["image"].string,
                        let priceArray = item["price"].array,
                        let priceObj = priceArray[0].dictionary,
                        let price = priceObj["price"]?.string,
                        let images = item["images"].string
                        else { return }
                        let itemPreview = Item(name: itemTitle, price: Double(price)!, productImageUrl: URL(string: stringValue), vendorImageUrl: URL(string: restaurantLogo))

                         itemsPreview.append(itemPreview)
                     }
                     addCardOfType(item: itemsPreview)
                }

        }
    }

}


private func addCardOfType(restaurant: [Restaurant]) {
    let customizationCard = ChatTableViewCell(message: nil, itemCustomizations: nil, restaurant: restaurant, categories: nil, item: nil)
    self.chatTableViewCell.append(customizationCard)
    self.addTableViewCellFrom(edge: UITableViewRowAnimation.left)
}

private func addCardOfType(categories: [Category]) {
    let categoryCard = ChatTableViewCell(message: nil, itemCustomizations: nil, restaurant: nil, categories: categories, item: nil)
    self.chatTableViewCell.append(categoryCard)
    self.addTableViewCellFrom(edge: UITableViewRowAnimation.left)
}

private func addCardOfType(item: [Item]) {
    let itemsPreviewCard = ChatTableViewCell(message: nil, itemCustomizations: nil, restaurant: nil, categories: nil, item: item)
    self.chatTableViewCell.append(itemsPreviewCard)
    self.addTableViewCellFrom(edge: UITableViewRowAnimation.left)
}

//once my array gets appended to, I call the following method to insert a row to my tableView, this row is the last item in the array

private func addTableViewCellFrom(edge: UITableViewRowAnimation) {
    let lastItem = IndexPath(item: self.chatTableViewCell.count - 1, section: 0)
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.insertRows(at: [lastItem], with: edge)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
    self.scrollToBottom()
}
```

So my questions are:
a) How should I isolate the delegate method into a different part?
b) What is the best way to create a parser that listens to the incoming type and do the JSON parsing job, and just returns the data to the ViewController?

Answer (score 1):

- Any part of the code that understand how the data is fetched or how the data is structured is considered Model
- You could make a `WebSocketController` that accepts a `URL` or `URLRequest` as well as a `WebSocketDelegate`. This makes it easy to create new WebSockets for new types of connections
- Now if you want to get the data in different parts of the app depending where you are you need to coordinate who gets a new message when. Typically you would create a Singleton-like class like `ChatMessageHandler`.
- It will do two things: allow listeners to register and deregister themselves and it will forward messages (in this case `ChatMessage`s) it receives from the WebSocket. The WebSocket should be built something like this:

  let delegate = ChatWebSocketDelegate(delegate: self)
  let socket = WebSocketController(connectingTo: url, delegate: delegate)
- Your `ChatMessageHandler` implements `ChatMessageHandling` which has some functions for the `ChatWebSocketDelegate` to call something like `received(newMessages: [Array])`
- This function will go over the array of registered listeners (`[ChatMessageListening?]` *) and send them the new messages. *retain loops!
- Sometimes there's a bit of logic like if you're watching the chat you receive the messages for you won't get a toaster notification in-app. This logic also lives in `ChatMessageHandler`.
- Your `ViewController` (or any object that wants to receive updates) only needs to implement `ChatMessageListening` in an `extension` and `register` and `deregister` itself with the `ChatMessageHandler`
- Typically register on `init` or `viewDidLoad`
- Deregister on `deinit`
- Remember to send `weak var weakSelf = self` as a listener otherwise you'll create retain loops! Another option is to make a weak copy inside the `register` function so you don't need to remember it every time